# Which blog should I be following for Stack Overflow / Stack Exchange news?

Tags: discussion, blog

My RSS reader is subscribed to both blog.stackoverflow.com and blog.stackexchange.com. Over the last few months they appear to have identical content.

Will this always be the case and if so which one should I be subscribed to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They will be identical for the forseeable future.