# Why isn't there any blog site for Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, blog, blog-overflow

I think this is very awkward thing that there is no blog site for Stack Overflow, whereas many of the Stack Exchange sites have their [own blog sites](https://stackexchange.com/blogs). Why isn't there any blog site for Stack Overflow? Is there any specific reason?

N.B: *I'm intentionally forgetting the fact that Stack Overflow hasn't a Twitter account!!!*

Comment: "intentionally forgetting". What is that supposed to mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a blog for Stack Overflow:
https://blog.stackoverflow.com/

It seems that [blog.stackoverflow.com](https://blog.stackoverflow.com) is managed by staff, rather than users of the site like smaller sites do.
And it is the same as [blog.stackexchange.com](http://blog.stackexchange.com).

Related reading:
[Which blog should I be following for Stack Overflow / Stack Exchange news?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64570/which-blog-should-i-be-following-for-stack-overflow-stack-exchange-news?rq=1)

Answer (score 5):

There *[is](http://blog.stackexchange.com/tags/stackoverflow/)* a Stack Overflow blog site. It is combined with the SE blog. Just filter on tag [stackoverflow](/questions/tagged/stackoverflow).

There is quite often a more development related blog post on that blog. I just consider Stack Overflow to be the 'main' site across the network. Putting the blog there is just convenient and historically grown like this.

Comment: That is a blog of Stack Exchange, Inc where only employees can post. The users of Stack Overflow do not have a blog.

Comment: Sorry, was that the question? @1999

Comment: @PatrickHofman Thanks to you also as because of finding a 'Stackoveflow' category I found [one more bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/264171/254554)