# SE new blog: Broken link on 'serverfault.com' and 'superuser.com' under 'TAGS'

Tags: bug, tags, blog

On SE's [**new blog**](http://blog.stackexchange.com/) main page some tag names are linked to broken links. Upon clicking on the '[serverfault.com](https://blog.stackexchange.com/tags/serverfault-com/)' and '[superuser.com](http://blog.stackexchange.com/tags/superuser-com/)' tags located in the right sidebar panel under 'TAGS' section (screenshot below)

> [image]

displays the following **error** message:

> ### Sorry, we can't find that page that you're looking for.
>
> You could [go back](http://javascript:history.go(-1);) or visit the [home page](http://blog.stackexchange.com/).
>
> If you've just run into a broken link, please report it at [our
>   feedback site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/).

As per Shadow Wizard's comment:

> Yep, for some odd reason the dot was replaced with "-" character,
>   breaking the URL. [This link](http://blog.stackexchange.com/tags/serverfault.com/) works.

**P.S.**

Apart from *main* page 'TAGS' section, I have also noticed the broken links for [serverfault.com](https://blog.stackexchange.com/tags/serverfault-com/)' and '[superuser.com](http://blog.stackexchange.com/tags/superuser-com/) in the '**Other Tags**' section. For example, here is a link to '[Stack Overflow blog](http://blog.stackexchange.com/tags/stackoverflow/)' page, see 'Other Tags' located in the right sidebar panel of the page.

> [image]

Comment: Yep, for some odd reason the dot was replaced with "-" character, breaking the URL. [This link](http://blog.stackexchange.com/tags/serverfault.com/) works.

Comment: Totally not related to the issue, but really curious - what happened to the red color in the left circle?? Did you run out of color? :D

Comment: @ShadowWizard I accidently used 'ink' pen instead of 'pencil' tool to circle. Sorry for the UI look. I hate myself as I am very particular (pixel perfect is my goal) but didn't wanted to bump the question.

Comment: Bumping after couple of hours won't even be noticed, that shouldn't stop you. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Ok. I added new screenshot and your comment in the post.